# Como obter um valor de um json a partir de uma string.string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tendo um JSON do tipo: `{"HOME":{"INTRODUCAO":"midias/video1.mp4"}}`

Como obter o valor `midia/video1.mp4` a partir da string

```
var key = "HOME.INTRODUCAO";
```

Já tentei:

```
var key = "HOME.INTRODUCAO";     

$.getJSON([CAMINHO DO JSON], function(j){

    alert(j.key);

});
```

Mas recebo a mensagem "undefined".

Comment: Já tentou usar o JSON.parse()? Ex: j = JSON.parse(j); alert(j.key);

Comment: Olá, infelizmente quando eu tento fazer o parse só obtenho a primeira letra da string. Mas vlw!

Comment: Olá Paulo! De onde vem esse JSON? Ele é uma string ainda ou objeto?

Comment: Olá Sergio, o JSON está em um arquivo separado. a minha variável "key" eu a obtenho assim: var key= $("#teste").attr('video');

Comment: Paulo, ok e o que dá se fiseres `console.log(typeof key, key);` depois dessa linha que indicaste?

Comment: Olá Sergio, eu fiz assim: 

var key=$("#teste").attr('video');
console.log(typeof key, key);

Eu recebi do console: "string HOME.INTRODUCAO".

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, pra acessar propriedades usando uma `string`, se usa colchetes (`[]`) e não ponto.

A função `getJson` devolve um objeto, você só precisa fazer `data["HOME"].["INTRODUCAO"]` para acessar essa propriedade.

```js
$.getJSON("http://ip.jsontest.com/", function(payload) {
  console.log(payload.ip);
  // ^ Pra mostrar que getJson retorna um objeto
  
  var fakeData = { HOME: { INTRODUCAO: 'midias/video1.mp4' } };
  // ^ é o formato que estará o objeto "data" no teu exemplo

  console.log(fakeData["HOME"]["INTRODUCAO"]);      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, mas eu recebo uma variável "key" com o valor "HOME.INTRODUCAO"  e precisava obter o valor do json através dessa variável.

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver meu problema da seguinte maneira:

```
                        var w = key.split(".");
                        var x = null;                            
                        for (i = 0; i < w.length; i++) { 

                            if(x==null){
                             x = j[w[i]];

                            }else{
                                 x = x[w[i]];
                            }
                        }
Obrigado!
```